# How to know what contacts were rejected for a journey builder interaction?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I have a DE being used as Entry Source in 5 interactions in Journey Builder.
Now for one of the journey say "Report Journey", the DE I have has around 200 contacts, but only 150 are getting injected into the journey.

When i go to view event results and try to check the contacts that failed, it shows results of all the interactions and has more than 3,000,000 records which makes it nearly impossible for me to find the contacts that got rejected or not yet injected into my "Report Journey".

In the Journey Builder -> Contacts screen, i tried querying for interaction name by modifying existing query

Original Query

> (status:Failed OR status:DidNotMeetEntryCriteria ) AND (
>   eventId:408f1634-ff7f-4cf5-8c39-224ab7b18910 OR
>   eventId:408F1634-FF7F-4CF5-8C39-224AB7B18910 )

My Modified Query - to search by interaction name.

> (Interaction Name:Report Pull) AND (
>   eventId:408f1634-ff7f-4cf5-8c39-224ab7b18910 OR
>   eventId:408F1634-FF7F-4CF5-8C39-224AB7B18910 )

This above is not returning any result. Probable something to do with column name and journey name having spaces.

Pls advise how can i check contacts accepted or rejected for a particular journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per SFMC Support

```
There is not currently a way to narrow down the search within the events page.

The reason the contacts are not getting injected is because they do not meet entry criteria.
```

This question can be marked as Solved as no further solution is possible.